# How to distinguish int from int pointer in C?

Tags: c

I got a scenario in which I want to distinguish these two types.
It is easy to make it in other language such as python, C++, java. But it is
hard in C. Maybe I am not good at the basics. I have no idea how to achieve this.

Let's say: [1,2,3,[34,45],45]. The internal array exists as an elements in other array. How can I tell them ordinary element from the array.

I just think this is interesting so that I can know more about the property of C.

Comment: In C every element of an array must have the same type

Comment: You would have to build considerable infrastructure to handle that in C.

Comment: See Implementing JSON with C.

Comment: [Implementation of omission](http://ideone.com/qEBwJa)

Comment: Yeah, I missed it. I missed the main difference between C and OOP languages.  Just think in the other direction. It is my mind bug.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is very simple: your array is impossible in C. Unlike Python and other high-level languages, C has a rather down-to-the-metal approach: all array elements must have the same type, otherwise your program is not going to compile.

In order to make an array that may have `int`s mixed with other arrays you need to do the following:

- Make a `union` that mixes an `int` and `int*`
- Put the `union` inside a `struct`, along with a flag that distinguishes between an `int` and an array
- Make an array of the `struct`s defined above

Here is a short example:

```
enum val_type {
    num
,   array
};

struct vect {
    int *arr;
    size_t size;
};

struct mix {
    union {
        int val;
        struct vect vect;
    } v;
    enum val_type type;
};

int arr1[] = {4, 5};

struct mix data[] = {
    {.v = {.val = 1}, .type = num}
,   {.v = {.val = 2}, .type = num}
,   {.v = {.val = 3}, .type = num}
,   {.v = {.vect = {.arr = arr1, .size = 2}}, .type = array}
,   {.v = {.val = 6}, .type = num}
};
```

Yes, you need all this for something that can be expressed as `[1,2,3,[34,45],45]` in some other languages. In return for all this code you get a program that has much higher efficiency than its counterparts written in higher-level languages.

Comment: It seems necessary to have the length or the end of the sequence.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the main difference between c and other oop language, OO. I just looked for in the other direction.  Thanks .

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are right, it's even more complex than that! I edited to add the length. Thank you!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Could you explain last 7 lines, or direct me to some article about this way of struct/union initialization? I'm not quite familiar with that. Thank you!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  I think an easier way to store this [1,2,3,[34,45],45] array in C is to use a 2D array. The first element of each inner array is the "size". So the array will be {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 34, 45}, {1, 45}}.

Comment: `.arr = arr1` does not create the space for th e`int` array and relies on a prior variable.  Perhaps could use a _compound literal_?

Comment: @ZhigangAn Here's your link: [C Struct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)). Read the "Struct initialization" section.

Comment: The data struct is only good for the one level. what if there are so many levels, like: [1,[2,[3,5]]].  That means there will be mix struct in mix, right?

Comment: @Wandy Not really: if you want unlimited nesting, forward-declare `struct mix`, and change `int *arr` to `struct mix* arr`.

Answer (score -1):

The other languages you are mentioning are object-oriented, where C is not. C can only manipulate arrays of same-type objects. To be able to have multiple types as elements, you will have to create a union type which can hold either.

```
union {
    int integer;
    int *pointer;
} myMixedArray[10] ;
```

Comment: This is not very useful as you also need to include some way of knowing whether each particular array member is the int or the pointer

Comment: Well maybe you know that the third one will be an array. Otherwise, you will need to bundle it with a type descriptor in a struct, as per @dasblinkenlight 's example